# Limit GPU Memory in Julia using CuArrays

Tags: julia, julia-gpu, cuda-arrays

I'm fairly new to julia and I'm currently trying out some deep convolution networks with recurrent structures. I'm training the networks on a GPU using 
CuArrays(CUDA Version 9.0).

Having two separate GPU's, I started two instances with different datasets. 
Soon after some training both julia instances allocated all available Memory (2 x 11GB) and I couldn't even start another instance on my own using CuArrays (Memory allocation error). This became quite a problem, since this is running on a Server which is shared among many people.

I'm assuming that this is a normal behavior to use all available memory to train as fast as possible. But, under these circumstances I would like to limit the memory which can be allocated to run two instances at the same time and don't block me or other people from using the GPU.
To my surprise I found only very, very little information about this.

I'm aware of the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES Option but this does not help since I want to train simultaneously on both devices. 
Another one suggested to call GC.gc() and CuArrays.clearpool() 
The second call throws an unknown function error and seems not to be within the CuArray Package anymore. The first one I'm currently testing but not exactly what I need. Is there any possibilty to limit the allocation of RAM on a GPU using CuArrays and Julia?
Thanks in advance
My Batchsize is 100 and one batch should have less than 1MB...

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such functionality. I quickly whipped something up, see https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CuArrays.jl/pull/379, you can use it to define `CUARRAYS_MEMORY_LIMIT` and set it to an amount of bytes that the allocator will not go beyond. Note that this might significantly increase memory pressure, a situation for which the CuArrays.jl memory allocator is currently not optimized (though it is one of my top priorities for the Julia GPU infrastructure).